# ARMA model with AR and MA coefficients having same magnitude but opposite sign

Tags: time-series, arima

After I identified the order of my time series, I got ARMA(3,3). I then estimated the parameters, and found that coefficients AR(3) and MA(3) are essentially opposite of each other (0.9926 vs. -0.9713). Other coefficients are essentially zero.

Does this indicate that the underlying process is likely white noise and ARMA model is not suitable?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429021/should-i-avoid-mixed-arma-models,